# Work out if the relationship between 2 datasets is constant

Tags: statistics, correlation, data-analysis

I have 2 one-dimensional datasets, let's call them `a` and `b`. I want to know the correlation between `a[n]` and `b[n]`, or if there *is* a correlation in the first place. What is the generic algorithm for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about `a` and `b` it's hard to say what the most general algorithm is.

The best place to start would be a non-parametric, or rank-based, measure of correlation such as [Spearman's $\rho$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) or [Kendall's $\tau$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient).  Both measure the similarity of the vectors `a` and `b` by sorting the values they contain and comparing the ranks.

These are convenient because there are no parametric assumptions about your vectors `a` and `b`, i.e. they are not assumed to come from a Gaussian or any other distribution, and there are approximate significance tests that can be performed.  Those significance tests will help you determine if there is correlation between the two vectors.